# How to create a new stored procedure template for Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-2005, code-snippets, code-templates

I would like to create a template for new stored procedures for our development team.

However, I can't seem to create template items for Database objects. I know for DLL/C#-related items, it's as simple as "File > Export Template ..."

How can I add new SQL templates to my Database project?

Here's my template:

```
IF EXISTS (select 1 from information_schema.routines where specific_schema = '_SCHEMA_' and routine_name = '_NAME_')
    BEGIN
        print 'Dropping Procedure _SCHEMA_._NAME_'
        DROP  Procedure  _SCHEMA_._NAME_
    END
GO

print 'Creating Procedure _SCHEMA_._NAME_'
GO
CREATE Procedure _SCHEMA_._NAME_
    (
        @parameter1 int
    ,   @parameter2 varchar(10)
    )
AS
BEGIN

END
GO

GRANT EXEC ON _SCHEMA_._NAME_ TO _ROLE_
GO
```

Thanks!

**Edit**: Wow, it's the first time I've had a question a whole day without any answers!

Is it just me, or does no one else use Item Templates?  I lead a number of developers, and it's easier to tell them "use this template" vs. "read the docs and do it that way".

Comment: What program is your team using to write these scripts?  I use SQL management studio myself and I wouldn't even thought to myself that it supported templates.

Comment: We use Visual Studio, and have a Database project that is linked to our development server.  Templates definitely exist for sprocs, tables, views, etc. in the dialog (if you right click, Add New Item...)  ... However, I want to install the custom template  (above) as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.

Here is the folder with the files:

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\Templates\Database Project Items

It's straight-forward to replace the **New Stored Procedure Script.sql** with your own.  If you want to add one (which I did) you can edit the **NewDataItems.vsdir** file to show a custom icon.

Answer (score 0):

Also see this SO question [How does one customize VS 2008 Database Item Templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827291/how-does-one-customize-vs-2008-database-item-templates)